# Looping through Jupyter directory and adding file names to a list

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, directory, jupyter

I have a simple file set up (about 15 .xlsx files in a larger file named FILE that is sitting on the home directory in Jupyter). I would like to loop through all the files that start with a certain combination of letters and then add those file names to a list. This is what I have so far. I would like to know: 1. What is the correct file path name? 2. How do I return the desired output?

```
import os

directory = '???/'   <--- to find this enter pwd into cell

file_name_list = []

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.startswith("SOME_LETTERS"):
        file_name_list.append(filename)
    else:
        continue
```

Example file setup:

```
FILE --> 
SOME_LETTERS_1.xlsx 
DIFFERENT_LETTERS_1.xlsx
ONE_NUMBER. xlsx
SOME_LETTERS_2.xlsx
DIFFERENT_LETTERS_2.xlsx
SOME_LETTERS_3.xlsx
SOME_LETTERS_4.xlsx
```

Desired output:

```
[SOME_LETTERS_1, SOME_LETTERS_2, SOME_LETTERS_3, SOME_LETTERS_4]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the glob module https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

From the docs:

> The glob module finds all the pathnames matching a specified pattern according to the rules used by the Unix shell, although results are returned in arbitrary order. No tilde expansion is done, but *, ?, and character ranges expressed with [] will be correctly matched.

Here is an example:

```py
from glob import glob

for file in glob("path/to/some/folder/*.txt"):
    print(file)
```

The code above will print the name of all .txt files in the given folder.

So in your case the code would be something like:

```py
"""
Folder structure:
├── samples
│   ├── Asample2.txt
│   ├── Bsample4.txt
│   ├── sample3.txt
│   ├── sample5.txt
│   └── sample.txt
└── stack.py
"""

from glob import glob
import os

# Using os.path.join so it works on multiple platforms
dir = os.path.join("samples", "*.txt")


 # os.path.basename extracts the file name from the fullpath
file_name_list = [file for file in glob(dir) if os.path.basename(file).startswith("s")]
print(file_name_list)
>>>['samples/sample5.txt', 'samples/sample.txt', 'samples/sample3.txt']
```

Another way this could be achieved by using Unix expansion:

```py
from glob import glob
import os

# Some letter here: ---------
#                             \
#                              v
dir = os.path.join("samples", "s*.txt")

file_name_list = [file for file in glob(dir)]
print(file_name_list)
```

Comment: Yes but I do not want all the files - I just want ones that start with a combination of letters and I want to add them to a list.

Comment: Do you need to define directory? Im getting an empty list

Comment: Yes you do need a directory. Try without the filter, see the results, the problem could the a wrong path or a wrong filter;

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! It worked and I learned a thing or two in the process :)